# How long will Ultegra 6800 parts be available?

Tags: groupsets

With the recent release of the new Ultegra 8000 groupset, is there an official word on how long Ultegra 6800 parts will be available?

Is Shimano still manufacturing Ultegra 6800 parts?  Or have they stopped producing 6800 and it's only a matter of how long resellers inventories will last?

Is there a way to somewhat reliably estimate the likelihood that, for example, an Ultegra 6800 50/34 170mm chainrings will be available 6 months from now?  A year from now?  2 Years from now?

For those with substantial past experience, with the release of a new Shimano groupset, how long do resellers still usually offer the previous group for?

Comment: Why do you need exactly Ultegra 6800? There are only a few standards, so replacements will be available.

Comment: From bitter experience, Ultegra brifter hoods may be available for only about 4-5 years after the groupset is superseded.  So if you're intent on riding your groupset a lot and keeping it for a long time, you might buy a replacement set of hoods within the next year or two.  Most other parts are either interchangeable or replaced in whole.

Answer (score 5):

Don't expect something official. If you don't see it listed on the main page of Shimano's website, production has likely ramped down or stopped.

Resellers will go as long as theres demand and stock. This also controls availability, and its tricky to estimate length of time, especially on less commodity groups (e.g. Ultegra vs Sora; you'll have a lot more Sora spare stock around, just cause a lot more people have Sora). Some retailers show stock levels on their websites, which could give you a rough idea.

This will also depend on your regionality and other things too, so don't expect something reliable.

---

That being said, you shouldn't worry if you want to just keep things working at a comparable level -- innovations from higher group sets do trickle down to lower ones. So, next year's 105 chainrings may be essentially identical to your Ultegra rings, for example. You could also mix with the new Ultegra (or other sets) where possible. It isn't the end of the world to not have a full set of one kind -- you'll be able to find parts in other group sets or manufacturers which are compatible (especially for things like chainrings). And if you really want a full set of one kind, well, you might end up ponying up for the new one in the future if its that important to you!

Of course, there are exceptions to the prior statement, when Shimano introduces a big incompatibility (e.g. mixing pre-97 ish dura ace with anything requires some trickery, and the Dura ace 7800 had extra tall splines making some compatibility issues for people; price of being on the edge, I suppose0.

Comment: Regarding "essentially identical", Shimano chainrings have been stamped up to 105 and CNC machined from Ultegra up since at least 9-speed times. I wouldn't expect that to change any time soon.

Comment: Someone may need to verify with first-hand experience, but from what I’ve heard, the R6800 and R8000 chainrings use a different bolt pattern and are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

11 speed is going to be available for some time.

Ultegra 6600 and 6500 are still readily available today.  6800 should not run out any time soon.

Comment: 8000 is 11 speed.  The question is specific to availability of 6800 components, not Ultegra 11 speed.

Comment: @RossMillikan I can read the question.   My answer is not limited to Ultegra 11 speed.  6600 and 6500 are not 11 speed.  "11 speed is going to be available for some time."   Can't predict when Ultegra 11 speed will run out.